How to convert messy dictionary definition string to array of short/summarized definitions as JSON, using open source AI tools?
I am able to convert messy dictionary data to a JSON array of definitions, a summary definition (i.e. a "gloss"), and perhaps the part of speech ("role"), using OpenAI's Node.js API like so:
import OpenAI from 'openai'
import 'dotenv/config'
import fs from 'fs/promises'

const PATH = `cleaned.json`

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_API_KEY,
})

async function main() {
  let i = 0
  const records = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(`messy.json`, `utf-8`))

  const outputs = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(PATH, 'utf-8'))

  for (const record of records) {
    if (outputs.find(o => o.term === record.word)) {
      i++
      continue
    }
    let text = await getText(record.def)
    try {
      if (typeof text === 'string') {
        try {
          text = text
            .split(/```json/)[1]
            .split(/```/)[0]
            .trim()
        } catch (e) {}
        // console.log(text)
        const output = JSON.parse(text)

        outputs.push({
          term: record.word,
          ...output,
        })
        console.log(i, i / records.length, record.word, output)

        await fs.writeFile(PATH, JSON.stringify(outputs, null, 2))
      } else {
        console.log(i)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      console.log(i)
    }

    i++

    async function getText(instructions: string) {
      const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'system',
            content: 'You are a helpful text summarizer.',
          },
          {
            role: 'user',
            content:
              `Extract the definitions from this set of messy definitions. Strip out the Tamil text and junk, and make the final set of definitions a small set. Don't include the definition if it says "See x", linking to other definitions. Simplify each definition if it's not already simplified, to ideally 1-3 word definitions, removing or merging duplicate or similar definitions where applicable. Omit otherwise meaningless text from the input, which doesn't appear to be English. It's okay if the definition is longer than 3 words if it can't easily be shortened. Send the definitions as a JSON array of strings under the "definitions" key. Finally, take your summarized definitions, and summarize those into one short definition (ideally also 1-3 words), and return that under the "gloss" JSON key. Format all definitions and the gloss in lowercase unless it is a proper name, and don't use abbreviations where they can be easily expanded to the normal word. And then also, add the part of speech of the word that's being defined in the "role" field. Also, be conservative. If you can't figure it out clearly and simply, then return empty JSON (i.e. return nothing). Better to be safe than sorry. That's it. Here is the input as JSON: ` +
              JSON.stringify(instructions.split(/\s*;\s*/), null, 2),
          },
        ],
        model: 'gpt-4o',
      })

      return completion.choices[0].message.content
    }
  }
}

main()

Here is the main prompt:

Extract the definitions from this set of messy definitions. Strip out the Tamil text and junk, and make the final set of definitions a small set. Don't include the definition if it says "See x", linking to other definitions. Simplify each definition if it's not already simplified, to ideally 1-3 word definitions, removing or merging duplicate or similar definitions where applicable. Omit otherwise meaningless text from the input, which doesn't appear to be English. It's okay if the definition is longer than 3 words if it can't easily be shortened. Send the definitions as a JSON array of strings under the "definitions" key. Finally, take your summarized definitions, and summarize those into one short definition (ideally also 1-3 words), and return that under the "gloss" JSON key. Format all definitions and the gloss in lowercase unless it is a proper name, and don't use abbreviations where they can be easily expanded to the normal word. And then also, add the part of speech of the word that's being defined in the "role" field. Also, be conservative. If you can't figure it out clearly and simply, then return empty JSON (i.e. return nothing). Better to be safe than sorry. That's it. Here is the input as JSON: [jsonArrayOfDefinitions].

It costs about $100 per 20,000 API calls to do this sort of summarization/cleaning + return results as JSON, using OpenAI's API.
Is there a way to accomplish this same thing using open source tools in Node.js (such as huggingface's transformers.js), or Python, for free, using open source models? If so, what is the general approach? Or if it's not possible, what is the state of the art of open source versions in comparison with OpenAIs paid-for API?
Here is an example of a definition input:

*அக்கடி akkaṭi , n. cf. akka + அடி. Difficulty, trouble in a voyage or journey, peril; அலைவு. எனக்கு அக்கடியா யிருக்கிறது. (R.)

And here is what OpenAI's API spit out:
{
  "term": "அக்கடி",
  "definitions": [
    "difficulty",
    "trouble",
    "peril"
  ],
  "gloss": "difficulty",
  "role": "noun"
}

Can it be done with open source? If so, what are the rough steps and/or pseudocode to get there?

Quickly pasting this question into ChatGPT, it says to use two models, but that the results won't be as high quality. So wondering what you would say instead, and how you might architect something as high quality as OpenAI's API using open source tools.

I suspect this would certainly possible, however depending on the performance of your computer you might be restricted in the size of the model you can run and the speed you can expect. There are quite a lot of different open source models you can use such as the models from Mistral or  more recently the Llama 3.1 model from Meta. There are multiple ways to use these models, these easiest ways are probably to use a library such as Huggingface's transformer library, or use one of the optimized CLI's available such as ollama or llama.cpp.

Can you elaborate on what I need to do with these models at a high level, to get text summarization on short definitions, and output as JSON?

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but since these are also LLM's just like OpenAI's ChatGPT. You therefore provide a prompt and ask your question just like you are currently doing using OpenAI's API. You might need to tweak the prompt a little bit given that they're different models.

Ok I requested access to Llama3.1, but it doesn't appear to work with Node.js, what models from this list are comparable to Minstrel and Llama that you mentioned?

The list you linked seems to contains several models from the Mistal/Llama/Phi family of models, however they generally seem to be much smaller with fewer parameters than the current state-of-the-art models, which might hinder performance.

Cool, also just saw this https://github.com/mlc-ai/web-llm

THANK YOU, I was able to get it working now! https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/855fdf60c243e26c0a5f02bd14bbbf4d
